# Не работает макрос Freemarker в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, freemarker, macro

Всем привет! Ребята, помогите плз разобраться с макросами Freemarker. Я абсолютный новичок в этой теме. Я возвращаю из контроллера страницу hello.ftl
[image: контроллер]
На странице hello.ftl импортируется другой ftl файл - main.ftl. Выглядит это следующим образом:
[image: hello.ftl]
Содержимое файла main.ftl - это простейший html шаблон, который обернут в <#macro> и принимает в себя hello.ftl вместо <#nested>:
[image: main.ftl]
После запуска приложения, я вижу следующее:
[image: localhost]
Почему макросы не работают в данном случае? Извините за мое примитивное изложение проблемы. Я повторюсь, что я только учусь.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Посмотрел подобное у себя - везде стоит слэш (`/`) перед файлом. Т.е., `<#import "/main.ftl" as main/>` в Вашем случае